# How to align center two pictures in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, image, alignment

How to align two pictures so that they are center of the div when using JqueryMobile and as far from the both sides? --p--p--

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" style="margin: 10px;"">
            <div class="ui-block-a" id="pic"   align="center">
                <img src="images/image1_100x100.jpg" data-theme="c" id="pictureId"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <label>&nbsp</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" id="pic"   align="center">
                <img src="images/image2_100x100.jpg" data-theme="c" id="pictureId2"/>
            </div>
        </div>

<style>

  div#pic { color:red; border:4px solid grey; border-radius: 15px; width:130px; height:130px 
         text-align:center; background-color: white; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
```

Second question is that what is the correct way to make a gap between divs? I am using now empty div, but I think that there might be something better?

Cheers,
Sami

Comment: Your code has an error: id's must be *unique*! Use pic as a class instead and don't use align=center as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I guess it is not so sophisticated solution, but it is working.

```
.pics {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 4px solid grey;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px !important;
}
.picLeft {
  float:left;
  margin-left: 10px !important;

}

.picRight {
  float:right;
  margin-right: 10px !important;

}
```

I am open to any better solutions and thanks Torsten!
Sami

Comment: since you use classes, you can join some of the properties, just give one class to both image containers and you can get rid of half the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add css to that and overwrite the JQM stuff when you insert your css *after* the JQM css links.
I took your code and modified it a little bit so it should give you a starting pont. I don't know if any of your or JQM css interferes with that as I can't try out right now.

The CSS in my case is in no way smaller because of all the compatibility css (prefixed properties). But the advantage is that box layout is a lot more flexible in that it also allows to center the content in 2 directions and also allows for sorting and alignment.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

This is just an alternative.

http://dabblet.com/gist/3132163

Comment: They are on top of each other (not quite) with those css-classes of yours. I am so bad with css staff...:( Do you mean that I need css-classes only for ui-grid-a? I tried to make another one like that: .pic {
    border:4px solid grey;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:130px;-------> Not working?
    height:130px; 
    text-align:center;
    background-color: white; 
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 0px;
    } And of course width is not working. With that divs are 50 % of the row, not 130 px any more.

Comment: JQM.css is overwriting my css, that's why width is not working
.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a, .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b { width: 49.95%; }
.ui-grid-a > :nth-child(n) { width: 50%; margin-right: -.5px; }
.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a { clear: left; }